# Voluptuous Exclusive Class

Tags: python, voluptuous

I am using voluptuous 0.9.2 and I have a problem with Exclusive class. I need that if there is none of the keys, it should give an error. However, this is okay for voluptuous. Is this a bug of voluptuous? If not, how I can write a script for that?

In order to clarify my problem, assume we built a schema like that:

```
schema = Schema({Exclusive('a', 'z'): int, Exclusive('b', 'z'): int, 'c': int}, required=True)
```

I need one and only one of the keys in exclusion group to be given.
But when I test with `{'c': 5}`, it seems to be valid even though I did not give either `a` or `b`.
I do not know how to make it works especially for this situation.

Comment: As of today, there is still an open issue asking for this functionality: https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous/issues/115

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://alecthomas.github.io/voluptuous/docs/_build/html/voluptuous.html), `Exclusive` inherits from `Optional`, which means that `a` and `b` are optional in your schema; that's why `{'c': 5}` is a valid input. To get around this problem, you need to explicitly specify them as required:

```
from voluptuous import Schema, Exclusive, Required
schema = Schema({Required(Exclusive('a', 'z')): int, Required(Exclusive('b', 'z')): int, 'c': int}, required=True)
```

Comment: Your solution makes a and b inclusive. It means that on the contrary if we give a, it also requires b. I want the opposite of that. I shall not give a and b together but only one of them.

Comment: In that case, can't you put a and b in the same group, namely use Exclusive('a', 'b')?

Comment: Exclusive('a','b') means a is a member of group b. I already put a and b into the same group namely z.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. `Required` seems to be overriding `Exclusive`.

Answer (score 1):

A trick that works here is to use two different schemas that need to validate at the same time:

```
from voluptuous import All, Any, Exclusive, Required                                                                                                                         

schema = All(                                                                                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                                                                                        
        Exclusive('a', 'z'): int,                                                                                                                                            
        Exclusive('b', 'z'): int,                                                                                                                                            
        Required('c'): int,                                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                                                                        
        Required(Any('a', 'b')): int,                                                                                                                                        
        Required('c'): int,                                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                       
)
```

The first schema fails to validate when both `a` and `b` are present and the second schema fails when neither `a` nor `b` are present. Hence, either `a` or `b` need to be present.

Comment: I would make 3 minor modifications to your solution: 1. You don't need to define 'c' in both schemas. You can choose one. 2. The keys-validation schema (the second one) should probably have `object` as types to avoid repeating values schema. 3. For error reporting sake, I would put the keys-validation schema first, so if you neglected to specify one of the keys you'll get the error first.

Comment: @guyarad Thanks for the suggestions. I agree on that there's no need to define `c` in both schemas and that only one of them needs to be specific on type while the other can just use `object`. However, I'm not sure if that would be more readable. Maybe a helper function that generates the final schema based on one without duplication would be a better solution.